# If anchor name is CONTACT open this url on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have menu:

```html
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li><a href="https://myplace.com/products/">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://myplace.com/services/">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://myplace.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

i would like to redirect anchor name **Contact** to  [othersite.com](https://othersite.com/)

Comment: just change the `href`? or if you want to open it in new tab add `target="_blank"` in anchor.

Comment: no-no, i can't change this html, that's the problem. but i can add javascript

Comment: You can: (1) change the `href` attribute of your link, (2) create a contact page and set a redirect to the other site there, (3) create a contact page containing an iframe which loads the content of the other site, (4) implement a redirect on server side. Probably I am forgetting some other options. Can you explain why you think it should be done via JavaScript or jQuery, please? Is there any particular requirement or constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention in the comments that you need to use JS to edit the `href` and that you can't modify the HTML, you can do it like this:

```js
var oldhref = "https://myplace.com/contact/"
var newhref = "https://othersite.com/"

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[href='" + oldhref + "']").prop("href", newhref)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main-menu">
  <li><a href="https://myplace.com/products/">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myplace.com/services/">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myplace.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

This will find the `a` element based on it's `href` and replace it with no modifications to the HTML.

A version that selects based on the link's text rather than it's `href`:

```js
var linkText = "Contact"
var newhref = "https://othersite.com/"

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a:contains('" + linkText + "')").filter(function(i) {
    return $(this).text() === linkText
  }).prop("href", newhref).attr("target", "_blank")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main-menu">
  <li><a href="https://myplace.com/products/">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myplace.com/services/">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myplace.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but can you provide code: find specific anchor name(s) (not url) and replace it...

Comment: @Gallex I've updated the answer with a version that works based on the link's text rather than it's `href`

Comment: that's it, thank you! could you add to your code one more thing: open that new link on new page (new tab)?

Comment: @Gallex I've added `.attr("target", "_blank")` to make the link open in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Find the element with id `main-menu` and add a `click` event listener. Also, using [`Event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) you can stop the default action that will be happening on click of an `anchor` element.

```js
document.getElementById("main-menu").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const { target } = event;
  if(target.innerHTML === "Contact") {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open("https://othersite.com/", '_blank');
  }
})
```

```html
<ul id="main-menu">
  <li><a href="https://myplace.com/products/">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myplace.com/services/">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myplace.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, It'll not replace but then when click on `Contact` it'll redirect to `https://othersite.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? u can replace the link in the Contact section with othersite.com

```
<ul id="main-menu">
<li><a href="https://myplace.com/products/">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="https://myplace.com/services/">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="https://othersite.com/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```